# How to trigger a Line break on a SMS

Tags: c#, sms, at-command, smpp

I'm gonna write SMS service that sends SMS's automatically.In that case i am going to create my SMS content by SQL.

**So is it possible to add a line break by using some special command or a character?**

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: yes.i used "%0a","\0x0A" & "/n".. but didn't successful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have concatenate **CHAR(10)** to my SQL message content an it worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried \n? I notice you say you've tried forward slash... Give back slash a try.

If that doesn't work, since you have tried the line feed character already (%0A), try carriage return (%0D) or a combination of the two (%0A%0D)

Edit: To let us help you better, what are you using to write this service? What technologies are involved here?

Comment: I'm sorry i have commented wrongly.. i have used "\n".And "%0A%0D" also not working.. i'm using SMPP for send SMS.

Comment: hmmm ok. Try the other combination of the line feed and carriage return characters (\r\n)

Comment: Environment.NewLine ?

Comment: Environment.NewLine may not be far off... If OP is using C#... Are you, @RangaNirmana?

Comment: But I'm using SQL Stored procedure for create my SMS content.. and found a solution